# How to count the number of repetitions of a specific word in specific fields of each document in the ElasticSearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm pretty new is ElasticSearch and will be thankful for the help.

I have an index.

It's an example of data:

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 20,
    "successful" : 20,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1834,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "profile_similarity",
        "_id" : "9c346fe0-253b-4c68-8f11-97bbb18d9c9a",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "US",
          "city" : "Salt Lake City Metropolitan Area",
          "headline" : "Product Manager"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "profile_similarity",
        "_id" : "e97cdbe8-445f-49f0-b659-6a19829a0a14",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "US",
          "city" : "Los Angeles",
          "headline" : "K2 & Amazon, Smarter King, LLC."
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "profile_similarity",
        "_id" : "a7a69710-4fad-4b7d-88e4-bd0873e6fd03",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "CA",
          "city" : "Greater Toronto Area",
          "headline" : "Senior Product Manager"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Its mappings:

```
{
  "profile_similarity_ivan" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "city" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "country" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
        "headline" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like for fields `country` and `headline` to count a number of specific words.
For example, if I search for 'US', an output might be like this:

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 20,
    "successful" : 20,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1834,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "profile_similarity",
        "_id" : "9c346fe0-253b-4c68-8f11-97bbb18d9c9a",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "US",
          "city" : "Salt Lake City Metropolitan Area",
          "headline" : "Product Manager",
          "country_count_US" : 1, 
          "headline_count_US" : 0
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "profile_similarity",
        "_id" : "e97cdbe8-445f-49f0-b659-6a19829a0a14",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "US",
          "city" : "Los Angeles",
          "headline" : "K2 & Amazon, Smarter King, LLC.",
          "country_count_US" : 1, 
          "headline_count_US" : 0
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "profile_similarity",
        "_id" : "a7a69710-4fad-4b7d-88e4-bd0873e6fd03",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "country" : "CA",
          "city" : "Greater Toronto Area",
          "headline" : "Senior Product Manager",
           "country_count_US" : 0, 
          "headline_count_US" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I notice that it can be done using `runtime` fields in `ElasticSearch` and scripting with `painless`

In general, I have issues with writing the painless script for this task.

Can you help me please write this script and create the right query in ElasticSearch for this task please?

Also will be thankful for any advice for this task can be finished by other functionality (not only by runtime fields) of `ElasticSearch`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but you need to fix three things.

You seem not to have created a mapping for your index, what you show look like the dynamic mappings ES assigns on its own to any given field. Even with your current mappings, you can simply run a terms aggregation on the results of your query and you will get the count of the words that you need. Just pass them as individual terms to be aggregated. Something like this will give you some output.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Country": "US"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "country_count": {
      "composite" : {
        "sources" : [
          {"country" : {"terms" : {"field" : "country"}}},
          {"id"  : {"terms" : {"field" : "_id", "include" : "US"}}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The compostie aggregation will return PER DOCUMENT, how many times the word "US" has come.
Just go look at the docs about how to paginate the composite aggregation. This way you can get all the required counts for EVERY SINGLE DOCUMENT.
[Composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)

Generally aggregations are used to get such answers. You may need to tweak the mappings of the fields, to use different analyzers(whitespace).

But generally you just need to use terms aggregations.

HTH.

Comment: thanks, but it's not what I need. I want to count the number of "US" in each specific document. Your solution counts "US" for all documents in the index

Comment: Solved, pls mark my answer as correct now!